# Displaying from moongoose database to index.jade

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pug

I am using nodejs, express and jade templating engine to display books from my database to the index.jade file, i want all the books in the database to displayed on the index.jade page

i created a the book model below

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/nodeauth');

var db = mongoose.connection;

var bookSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    category: String,
    description: String,
    author: String,
    publisher: String,
    price: Number,
    stock: Number,
    cover: String
});
```

var Book = module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema, 'books');

i called my bookModel in the index.js Below in the get request that renders the index.jade view

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var Book = require('../models/bookModel');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    Book.find({}, function (err, books) {
        if (err) {console.log(err);}

        res.render('index', {books: books}, { title: 'Members' });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

the problem is that it keeps running an endless loop with out displaying anythin

this is my index.jade

```
extends layout

block content
    .content
       each book in books
           .book
               img(src="/images/book.cover", width="150px", height="200px")
               h4.book-title book.title
               h6.book-dtls Price: book.price SDG
               p.book-desc book.description
               a.btn.btn-primary.view(href="/books/details/book._id") View Book
```

Comment: Could you please log the books in the controller handler and attach the logs here? Also please provide the rendered html

Comment: it logs all the books in my database but not rendering them

Answer (score 0):

first use `#{book.title}` to show data on pug

```
 img(src="/images/book.cover", width="150px", height="200px")
           h4.book-title #{book.title}
           h6.book-dtls Price: #{book.price} SDG
           p.book-desc #{book.description}
           a.btn.btn-primary.view(href="/books/details/book._id") View Book
```

and may be there is problem in `book.books`.

So first you should use `console.log(book)` to check data

`